# how to randomly open up lines for maze in java

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I am making a maze and I would like to use the recursive method as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Recursive_division_method). However, I need some help as to how to randomly open up the lines once I randomly draw them. Right now I'm creating the lines (walls of the maze) simply by drawing them with their beginning and end x- and y-coordinates. I just can't seem to find a simple way to "erase" (or "open up") parts of the lines.

EDIT: Okay I need to be slightly more specific. How could I randomly select places on *each* line to "open up?"

EDIT 2: Here is some code of what I'm trying to do:

```
public static void draw() {
    // picks a random spot in the rectangle
    Random r = new Random();
    int x0 = r.nextInt(w)
    int y0 = r.nextInt(h)

    // draws the 4 lines that are perpendicular to each other and meet
    // at the selected point
    StdDraw.line(x0, 0, x0, y0);
    StdDraw.line(0, y0, x0, y0);
    StdDraw.line(x0, h, x0, y0);
    StdDraw.line(w, y0, x0, y0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {   
    // set up the walls of the maze
    // given w = width and h = height
    StdDraw.setXscale(0, w);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0, h);

    StdDraw.line(0, 0, 0, h);
    StdDraw.line(0, h, w, h);
    StdDraw.line(w, h, w, 0);
    StdDraw.line(w, 0, 0, 0);

    draw();
}
```

Now I just need to figure out how to randomly select 3 of these lines, and for each line randomly erase a portion.

Comment: Not fair changing the question ;)  While it's an interesting problem, it's easier to help if you post some source code revolving around the problem.

Comment: *"How could I randomly select places on each line to "open up?""*  You seem to believe that 'randomly opening up lines' will produce a valid and logical maze.  I OTOH think it won't.  The first task here should be figuring out how to create a shape for the maze.

Comment: @NickRippe I've added some code. I know this is probably really really simple code, but I'm just starting with CS so that's what I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `swing` and the `paintComponent` method, you would set the `Graphic`'s color to the background color and draw over the line again.  Here's an example:

```
public class DrawTest extends JPanel{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawTest());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(400,300);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(10, 10, 100, 10);
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.drawLine(50, 10, 60, 10);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I suppose you're not creating the Maze in the `paintComponent` method (or you'd end up with a new maze every time you repainted).  So, I'd recommend creating a sub-class similar to below and storing instances of it in an `ArrayList` field of your main class.  Then you can iterate through your `ArrayList` when you're doing your panting.

```
public static class MazeWall{
    public static final int OpeningWidth = 10;

    Point start;
    Point end;
    Point opening;

    public MazeWall(Point start, Point end, boolean hasOpening){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        if(hasOpening){
            int range;
            if(start.x == end.x){
                range = end.x - start.x - OpeningWidth;
                int location = (int)(Math.random() * range + start.x);
                opening = new Point(location, start.y);
            } else{
                range = end.y - start.y - OpeningWidth;
                int location = (int)(Math.random() * range + start.y);
                opening = new Point(location, start.x);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```